# How to execute shell command in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I wrote this code in jest.

```
const { createConnection } = require("mysql2");
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

describe("My DB Testing", () => {
  beforeEach(()=>{
    //Reset my database;
    const connection = createConnection([mysql scheme]);
    const db = connection.config.database;
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${db}`);
    connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${db}`);
    connection.query(`USE ${db}`);
    connection.end();

    //Migration
    execSync("sequelize db:migrate");
    execSync("sequelize db:seed:all");  
  })
  test("My test code", () => {
    //my test codes;
  })
})
```

I expected a table in DB to be created, but no table was created in DB.
"sequelize db:migrate" in terminal works, but in jest does not work;
Please tell me the reason.

Comment: Syntax Error in code

Comment: sorry, I fixed my code. but still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `{stdio: 'inherit'}` to the `execSync()` to see the output of the commands, so you can get information on what was wrong with executed commands.

```js
//Migration
execSync("sequelize db:migrate", {stdio: 'inherit'});
execSync("sequelize db:seed:all", {stdio: 'inherit'});
```

Second, add callback functions to `query` functions to see if something is wrong with them.

```js
connection.query(`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${db}`,
  function(err, results) {
    console.log(err ? err : results);
  }
)
```

The output tells you the real reason. Possible errors are:

- `sequelize` may not be in the path where the code is executed.
- Executed `query` functions may have errors returned from database.